# I was charged Geo-Replication v2 Data Transfer, but for unknown reason

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I was charged Geo-Replication v2 Data Transfer ($0.19), but for unknown reason, as my account is only for testing in Texas (US Central) area. But as far as I know I won't be charged if Transfer data in the same area.

[here is the cost analysis image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3ITC.png)

I've tried contacting auto support but it's not too possible with those pre-existing questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your storage account must be set to **Geo-redundant storage (GRS)**, it's the default setting. You can change the redundancy to **LRS** to avoid geo-replication costs.

[image]